# Strtotime can't be used for comparison with meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce, and trying to check for late payments. Any orders paid after 6 pm (sometimes the payment gateway is a bit slow) every day, got put back to 'on-hold' status. I want this treatment to apply only to orders with tomorrow delivery dates.

This is not working (the 'on-hold' status never implemented):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'check_late_payment' );

function check_late_payment( $order_id ){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    if (time() > strtotime("18:00:00")) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_orddd_timestamp', true ) == strtotime('tomorrow') ) {
            $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );
        }       
    }
}
```

BUT, this is working:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'check_late_payment' );

function check_late_payment( $order_id ){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    if (time() > strtotime("18:00:00")) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_orddd_timestamp', true ) == '1531785600' ) {
            $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );
        }       
    }
}
```

The only difference is the strtotime and constant string. I've checked the meta value, it's exactly as strtotime ('tomorrow'). 
Any ideas why this isn't working?
As I need it to be always tomorrow's timestamp.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you comparing to a single, fixed unix timestamp value? You know that this is not “a day”, but one single second only, right? So all your relevant orders that you want to get here, have that specific second of the day set as the order timestamp …?

Comment: Did you tried assigning `strtotime('tomorrow')` to a variable and compare it?

Comment: @CBroe You're correct, all delivery date format are set to that specific time, the date at 00:00:00. It's unusual, I know.

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress Yes, I did try that, even put the meta value in a variable and try to compare it, not working.

Comment: Have you tried echoing `strtotime('tomorrow')` which echoes same '1531785600' (just to confirm timezone issue)?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress Yup, tried that too, the result is exactly the same, at least for today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_orddd_timestamp', true ) == (string)strtotime('tomorrow') )` and let me know whether its working.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, still not working, the condition isn't triggered.

Comment: Have you tried assigning both meta and 'strtotime' values as string in separate variables and compare both?

Comment: I did, it's one of the first things I tried, not working. Never mind, I'm going to try to use a different approach for this matter, this has been taking too much time for such simple task. Thanks for your help my friend, appreciated it.

Comment: Then there should be some issues with your meta value data, try alerting both as a last try.

Comment: Actually I use an export plugin, which can export meta values etc. I did a side by side comparison with the strtotime tomorrow, they're perfectly identical, no extra spaces or any other characters. Strange..